# Way to add reverb in iMovie

Tags: audio, imovie

I know its possible in Garageband but is there a way to apply a reverb effect to video or audio clips in iMovie?

By the way I have iMovie Version 10.0.6 installed on my mac.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From 10.0.5 [not sure about 10.0.6 as that's Yosemite only]

Top bar, to the right of the icons, next to the info button, then below, Audio Effect...
 3rd row, one of the rooms or cathedral

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in iMovie to add some reverb effects by going to the audio effects panel. You can get there in iMovie by clicking on the filters tab above the clip preview window. In the tab options there select "Audio Effects" and the Small Room, Medium Room, Large Room and Cathedral presets apply different amounts of reverb.

For more precise control however, I believe you still have to go into Garageband to apply the effect.

YouTube video I made about how to apply audio filters iMovie 10: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6qDOaNwLXY

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been five years since you asked this (ha) but my friend and I just built an app to do this. It's called Audio Sauce. I kept waiting for someone to make something to do this and nobody did. So we built our own. Check it out on the app store.

Or our website. Audio-sauce.com

Comment: This app looks excellent!